# Using Endpoint.publish() in OSGi to publish web service?

Tags: java, web-services, osgi, endpoint

Is there a way to use Endpoint.publish() in an OSGi bundle to publish a web service? When I run the code from the command line it works, but the same code in a bundle activator produces the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: [failed to localize] cannot.load.wsdl(file:/C:/ws/project/org.project.configuration/xml/Configuration.wsdl)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.getPrimaryWsdl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
at org.project.internal.configuration.Activator.start(Activator.java:52)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
... 11 more
Root exception:
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: [failed to localize] cannot.load.wsdl(file:/C:/ws/project/org.project.configuration/xml/Configuration.wsdl)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.getPrimaryWsdl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
at org.project.internal.configuration.Activator.start(Activator.java:52)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)
```

Comment: From the stack trace `cannot.load.wsdl(file:/C:/ws/project/org.project.configuration/xml/Configuration.wsdl)`... does this file exist?

Comment: Yeah, it exists. If I ran this same code outside OSGi, it worked without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was able to finally solve this by adding the annotation: `@WebService(endpointInterface, name, serviceName, targetNamespace)` to the service implementation.